# Disable entire dropdown with knockoutjs observable

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which represents a Viewmodel and associated HTML for display using Knockout.js. I would like to work out how to disable the entire dropdown control (not just a single select item) if 'IsAnnualLeave' is true.

Viewmodel:

```
function viewModel(){

    var self=this;

    self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels = ko.observableArray();

    self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(1, 'Test 1', false));
    self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(2, 'Test 2', false));
    self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(3, 'Test 3', true));

    function TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(AssignmentID, CodeName, IsAnnualLeave) {
        var self = this;
        this.AssignmentID = ko.observable(AssignmentID);
        this.CodeName = ko.observable(CodeName);
        this.IsAnnualLeave = ko.observable(IsAnnualLeave);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels,
            optionsValue: 'AssignmentID', optionsText: 'CodeName',
            value: 3, optionsCaption: '-- please select --',
            disable: IsAnnualLeave "></select>
```

How do I reference the current item in my observable array  'viewModel.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels' in order to do this?

I have tried accessing the property directly using:

```
disable: IsAnnualLeave
```

However, that does not work. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/5/

Comment: You should consider posting a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or some place like that. That will make it easier posting a working solution to your question

Comment: You'll be able to achieve this with either a computed observable or just referencing the current item directly in the `disable` binding.  In order to give a full answer though, seeing your viewmodel will help.

Comment: jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/4/

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would like to work out how to access the currently selected item in the dropdown rather than always getting the value from the third item in the array.

If you want to access selected item in the dropdown you have to define an observable that holds the selected items value.

```
 self.selected=ko.observable();
```

After that you have to tell ko to bind this with value binding.

```
<select data-bind="options:List,value:selected"></select>
```

Then you can access it from your ViewModel. In your case you have already binded
a value `value: AssignmentID`.

I dont know if the `AssignmentID` is observable but if its not you have to make it observable. Then you can access it. Here is a sample for you : [Sample observableArray selection](http://jsfiddle.net/vj3jLef6/1/)

> What I'm trying to accomplish is to disable the entire dropdown control when my web page loads existing data only when the currently selected item has the observable of 'IsAnnualLeave' set to 'true'.

**Update 2:**

The problem is how to handle selection changing and update selected elements disable property with knockout. You can use event binding for that.

```
event:{change:$root.evnt}
```

And in the viewModel you just simply:

```
    self.evnt=function()
{
    //change logic here.

}
```

In your case you have to bind the selected item in a ko.observable and bind change event. Then you can modify your select item property. You can bind observables to visible and disable attributes of an html element.

Here is the  full code:
Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels,optionsValue: 'IsAnnualLeave', optionsText: 'CodeName',disable:dis,value:selected,event:{change:$root.evnt}"></select>
```

javascript:

```
function viewModel(){

var self=this;
    self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels = ko.observableArray();

self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(1, 'Test 1', false));
self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(2, 'Test 2', false));
self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels.push(new TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(3, 'Test 3', true));

self.selected=ko.observable();
self.dis=ko.observable(false);

self.evnt=function()
{
    if(self.selected()){
    self.dis(true);
    }
}

function TimeEntryAssignmentViewModel(AssignmentID, CodeName, IsAnnualLeave) {
    var self = this;
    this.AssignmentID = ko.observable(AssignmentID);
    this.CodeName = ko.observable(CodeName);
    this.IsAnnualLeave = ko.observable(IsAnnualLeave);
}
```

}

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

The jsfiddle file: [NewJsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/6/)

**Update 3**

Well, if you absolutely want to bind your `AssignmentID` to the selected value that means a bit of extra work. First you have to iterate your observableArray and then check if any of items `IsAnnualLeave` property is false. Then visible the select.

new Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels,optionsValue: 'AssignmentID', optionsText: 'CodeName',disable:dis,value:selected,event:{change:$root.evnt}"></select>
```

change the evnt function in ViewModel:

```
self.evnt=function()
{
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TimeEntryAssignmentViewModels(), function(item) {
    var value = item.IsAnnualLeave();
         if(value){
         self.dis(true);
         }
});
```

`ko.utils.arrayForEach` is what you need. You can find a lot of info about utils here :[Utils](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

And the final fiddle:[Final](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/7/)

Comment: Kyur - thanks I have reproduced the issue on jsFiddle using your example as a starting point.

Comment: Kyur - thanks for the update and very speedy reply. That seems a lot closer to what I need. However, I need my optionsValue to be the identifier which binds to the model. This is represented by the 'AssignmentID' property. Given that requirement, what would be the solution?

Comment: kyur - thanks for helping once more. This is closer again to the answer! I have played around with the fiddle, But it also disables if I select 'test 2' which is set to false. It should only disable when the third option is populated from the model or selected. I will have a look at the Utils info you referenced.

Comment: Kyur, thanks to you I have managed to create a workaround using a combination of jquery and Knockout. Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Lm5zyLvg/13/